# Promotion condition rule

Tags: promotions

I have a little problem with my condition and action in the promotion in Magento.

In my cart, i can add differents product like 1kg, 2kg .. 10kg.

I can have more than `2 kg product like : 2kg items x2`

If I have a `2kg item, a free things is add in my cart.` This `part is ok, but how can i add another free things if i add new 2kg item`. For the moment it only add 1 even i add a same product after.

Comment: It's hard to visualize your question here... perhaps you could begin by showing us the code you're using now.